# Get list of courses with username in moodle programmatically from database

Tags: moodle

I need to get the list of all courses available with their username who created it in moodle site programmatically from database. As I am using drupal with moodle. In drupal I connected the moodle database so I need to fetch the courses with username for further development. Please help me on this.
Regards
Neha Singhania

Answer (score 0):

The only place where you can find out who created a course is in the mdl_log table. Look for an entry with module = course and action is something like 'create' (I haven't got the code in front of me right now to check). The 'course' field will match the id of the mdl_course table, where you can find the course name (fullname / shortname). The user field will match the id of the mdl_user table, where you can find the firstname, lastname and username for the user.